# What is the best Javascript charting library out of these three: HighCharts, ChartJS, and ECharts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm currently researching these three javascript charting libraries. My task is to find the best one for my current project.

Our frameworks are: Angular, python, and we'll be building our own database.

Our data will be not hundreds but thousands of data points. We will be showing basic graphs, with customizable graphs.
I was hoping to get some insight from users that have worked with any of these three libraries. the criteria that I'm using:

- Ease of use
- Type of visualizations supported
- Performance (SVG or Canvas)
- Theme-ability / Customization
- Responsiveness / Mobile support
- Internationalization support
- Accessibility
- Product support / Update frequency
- Security concerns
- Cost

I have most of this information but I wanted to see if anyone could tell me other information that would be a deciding factor into which charting library is best.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Syncfusion chart library

1. 50+ Chart types
2. Fast-paced performance
3. Elegant animation
4. Simple configuration and APIs
5. Supports all modern browsers
6. Mobile-touch friendly and responsive
7. Detailed documentation

Angular: https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-components/angular-charts
JavaScript: https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-charts

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion